# dynamical change td width with js

Tags: javascript

I need to change the width of a td using javascript.  The value of the width will be pulled in and then I need to multiple it to get a percentage.  I just need to know how to write the js so far I have got to here but it is not working

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var divWidth = 66*0.4;

document.write("<td width="+divWidth+">");

document.getElementById("myRow").write("<td width="+divWidth+">");

</script>


<table>
<tr>
    <td id="myRow"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var divWidth = 66*0.4;
  document.getElementById("myRow").setAttribute('width', divWidth);//defaults to pixels
  //or if you really want this as a percentage
  document.getElementById("myRow").setAttribute('width', divWidth+'%');//percent
</script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="myRow"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, there are some things I would adjust in your code.  I changed the language attribute in the script tag (now deprecated) to a `type="javascript"`.  The `id` on your TD element is `myRow` I would change this to something reflecting the *cell* vs. the *row*.

Comment: One word of advice, styling attributes and tags are deprecated. Use style instead.

Comment: @Ben - I would agree, although getting the exact behavior you want using CSS in IE may lead to some frustration.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it's a Javascript library/framework and what you're trying to do above will be ten times easier using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

With jQuery, your code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newWidth = $("#myRow").width();
    $("#myRow").width(newWidth*0.4);
}
```

//edit:

Sorry, I had the multiple wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind Kristina that the "4" would be replaced with whatever percentage you see fit.